# Touchscreen not working in android on beagleboard xM

Tags: android, touchscreen, beagleboard

I have a custom Android (2.3) running on a Beagleboard xM. Currently we are trying to replace a small resistive touchscreen with a bigger, capacitive one. However we can't seem to get the touch working with our android. (The resistive always worked fine).

The kernel modules are loaded and the driver is running. The driver outputs the correct touch coordinates when the screen is pressed.

/proc/bus/input/devices contains these entries:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=7458 Version=0210
N: Name="eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7200-7458"
P: Phys=usb-ehci-omap.0-2.3/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/ehci-omap.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.3/1-2.3:1.0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=421 0 30001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=100 3f
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0006 Vendor=0eef Product=0020 Version=0001
N: Name="eGalaxTouch Virtual Device for Multi"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event2 
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=6608000 1000003

I: Bus=0006 Vendor=0eef Product=0010 Version=0001
N: Name="eGalaxTouch Virtual Device for Single"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event3 
B: EV=b
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3
```

which are correct, according to the guide for the device.

When touching the screen android shows this in logcat:

```
V/EventHub(10978): /dev/input/event2 got: t0=1594, t1=229858, type=0, code=0, v=0
D/InputReader(10978): Input event: device=0x10002 type=0x0 scancode=0 keycode=0 value=0
V/EventHub(10978): /dev/input/touchscreen0 got: t0=1594, t1=235198, type=3, code=53, v=788
D/InputReader(10978): Input event: device=0x10001 type=0x3 scancode=53 keycode=53 value=788
V/EventHub(10978): /dev/input/event2 got: t0=1594, t1=235198, type=3, code=53, v=788
D/InputReader(10978): Input event: device=0x10002 type=0x3 scancode=53 keycode=53 value=788
V/EventHub(10978): /dev/input/touchscreen0 got: t0=1594, t1=235382, type=3, code=54, v=1512
D/InputReader(10978): Input event: device=0x10001 type=0x3 scancode=54 keycode=54 value=1512
V/EventHub(10978): /dev/input/event2 got: t0=1594, t1=235382, type=3, code=54, v=1512
D/InputReader(10978): Input event: device=0x10002 type=0x3 scancode=54 keycode=54 value=1512
V/EventHub(10978): /dev/input/touchscreen0 got: t0=1594, t1=235473, type=3, code=0, v=788
D/InputReader(10978): Input event: device=0x10001 type=0x3 scancode=0 keycode=0 value=788
```

This also seems to be correct, the code 53 and 54 are for the X and Y coordinates.

However the android UI is not reacting to the touch inputs. Neither is our own app, nor the pointer painter from the development tools. Are the events not forwarded to the input dispatcher? The problem seems to be on the android side, but I cannot figure it out.

I hope someone can help me there or at least tell me where I can find additional information.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: I had to adjust the touchscreen driver to our kernel. Small explanation is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/android-porting/EUwI2ufV9kk